# Inputting a list of unique numbers in Scratch

Tags: performance, scratch

So I am working on recreating a hidden minigame from PvZ Brutal Mode EX+/Unnamed Mod in Scratch for fun [here](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/912472409/). While I am making some considerable progress on it, I'm having trouble simplifying the code for choosing the plants you want to use before going into the minigame.

What I am doing right now is using a list of answers , and if when answering, there happens to be numbers outside of what is allowed, the project just stops so I won't have to deal with removing the forbidden answers individually.

Here are the restrictions:

$$\text{The project stops if: }\begin{cases}a_n\not\equiv0\pmod1\\a_n\gt25\\a_n\lt1\end{cases}\\\text{where }a_n\text{ is being referred to here as answer }n$$

The project also stops if it detects that an answer is the same as a previous answer.

Here is the code (not in `scratchblocks` format):
[image]

In `scratchblocks` format (best I could do, there might be errors):

```
[scratchblocks]
when I receive [Done loading v]
delete all of [answers v]
repeat (9)
ask [What plants would you like to use?] and wait
if <<((answer) mod (1)) = [0]> and <<not <(answer) > [25]>> and <not <[1] > (answer)>>>> then
insert (answer) at (((length of [answers v] :: list) + (1)) v) of [list v]
if <not <(length of [answers v] :: list) < [2]>> then
set [c1 v] to [1]
repeat ((length of [answers v] :: list) - (1))
if <(item (c1 v) of [answers v] :: list) = (item ((length of [answers v] :: list) v) of [answers v] :: list)> then 
stop [all v]
else
change [c1 v] by (1)
end
end
end
else
stop [all v]
end
end
[/scratchblocks]
```

<sub>Note that the "delete all of [answers]" block is there only for testing purposes. Overall, this part of the project (except the "delete all of [answers]" block) takes up 36 blocks.</sub>

---

Can this code be improved, or is this as optimized as it can get?

---

<sub>Note: the code can be found in the backdrops. This does work as intended.</sub>